# Compare each class attribute value using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a below class. I will get two objects `List<Client> data1` and `List<Client> data2`. I want to compare data1 and data2 with each of the attribute value.

For example, if data1 object has the LastName=a and ClientId=1,..etc and if data2 list has the same set of data i want to push that into one more list.
Any idea, how can we achieve this using LINQ/Minimal code?

```
public class Client 
{
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you class implement the [IComparable<T> Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: No. It does not implement the IComparable<T> Interface

Answer (score 1):

using Intersect

```
    List<Client> data1 = new List<Client>();
    List<Client> data2 = new List<Client>();
    List<Client> newlst = new List<Client>();

    Client obj = new Client();
    obj.ClientId = 1;
    obj.LastName = "a";
    obj.FirstName = "n";
    obj.Email = "e";

    data1.Add(obj);
    data2.Add(obj);

    obj = new Client();
    obj.ClientId = 2;
    obj.LastName = "a";
    obj.FirstName = "f";
    obj.Email = "e";

    data1.Add(obj);
    newlst = data1.Intersect(data2).ToList();
```

Comment: I have used the Intersect in my case. But that's not working for me. If i use data1.Intersect(data1) will work. But if i try to intersect with data2 its giving me count =0. I am sure data are equal. Should i need to do something with IEqualityComparer?

Comment: Yes, the empty results indicates that the default comparer isn't sufficient for your purposes so creating an implementation of IEqualityComparer is the way to go.

Comment: @Nam how can it give you `count = 0` if this code has `count = 1` in the example. are you not maybe doing something wrong? intersect should work, I would still implement the IEqualityComparer though.

Comment: Yes, above code gives me count=1, but in my example it always gives me count = 0; after adding IEqualityComparer gave me correct value. I am upvoting this for giving me an idea so that I am able to google and implement the IEqualityComparer .

Answer (score 1):

I have used IEqualityComparer which is used to compare both the collection and Intersect will give the common value.I have tested the code for few scenario. You can check for all the scenario.

Hope this code will be helpful.

```
namespace UnitTestProject
{
    [TestClass]
    public class CompareTwoGenericList
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            var coll = GetCollectionOne();
            var col2 = GetCollectionTwo();

            //Gives the equal value
            var commonValue = coll.Intersect(col2, new DemoComparer()).ToList();

            //Difference
            var except=coll.Except(col2, new DemoComparer()).ToList();
        }

        public List<Demo> GetCollectionOne()
        {
            List<Demo> demoTest = new List<Demo>()
            {
                new Demo
                {
                    id=1,
                    color="blue",
                },
                new Demo
                {
                    id=2,
                    color="green",
                },
                new Demo
                {
                    id=3,
                    color="red",
                },
            };

            return demoTest;
        }

        public List<Demo> GetCollectionTwo()
        {
            List<Demo> demoTest = new List<Demo>()
            {
                new Demo
                {
                    id=1,
                    color="blue",
                },
                new Demo
                {
                    id=2,
                    color="green",
                },
                new Demo
                {
                    id=4,
                    color="red",
                },
            };

            return demoTest;
        }
    }

    // Custom comparer for the Demo class
    public class DemoComparer : IEqualityComparer<Demo>
    {
        // Products are equal if their color and id are equal.
        public bool Equals(Demo x, Demo y)
        {
            //Check whether the compared objects reference the same data.
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

            //Check whether any of the compared objects is null.
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
                return false;

            //Check whether the demo properties are equal.
            return x.color == y.color && x.id == y.id;
        }

        // If Equals() returns true for a pair of objects
        // then GetHashCode() must return the same value for these objects.

        public int GetHashCode(Demo demo)
        {
            //Check whether the object is null
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(demo, null)) return 0;

            //Get hash code for the color field if it is not null.
            int hashColor = demo.color == null ? 0 : demo.color.GetHashCode();

            //Get hash code for the id field.
            int hashId = demo.id.GetHashCode();

            //Calculate the hash code for the product.
            return hashColor ^ hashId;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Create Your new class ClientView**

```
public class ClientView{
 public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

List lst = new List();

```
                var data = from n in db.client

                           select new ClientView()
                           {
                               ClientId = n.ClientId ,
                               LastName = n.LastName ,
                               FirstName = n.FirstName,

                           };
               var data1 = from n in db.client

                           select new ClientView()
                           {
                               ClientId = n.ClientId ,
                               LastName = n.LastName ,
                               FirstName = n.FirstName,

                           };
                lst.AddRange(data);
                lst.AddRange(data1);

List<ClientView> lst1 = new List<ClientView>();
                foreach (var singlelst in lst)
                {

                    ClientView newClient = new ClientView ();
                    newClient.Id = singlelst.Id;
                    newClient.આપેલ = singlelst.LastName;
                    newClient.આપેલતારીખ = singlelst.FirstName;
                    lst1.Add(newClient);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetVariance(Client user)
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo pi in user.GetType().GetProperties()) {

        object valueUser = typeof(Client).GetProperty (pi.Name).GetValue (user);
        object valueThis = typeof(Client).GetProperty (pi.Name).GetValue (this);

        if (valueUser != null && !valueUser.Equals(valueThis))
            yield return pi;

    }
}

IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> variances = data1.GetVariance (data2);

foreach (PropertyInfo pi in variances)
      Console.WriteLine (pi.Name);
```